# Responsive Design and XAML

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am developing Windows Store app using Visual Studio 2013 with update 5 in Windows 8.1, but now we move on to windows 10, and issue arise is responsive in XAML.

I want to know is it possible to design Windows Store application behavior is responsive with existing Visual Studio version 2013?

I explore it how to responsive Windows Store app, but Visual Studio gives this in VS version 2015 and 2017 like relative panels properties, and triggers etc. So, but I can do this in Visual Studio in 2013 version.

Comment: By "responsive design" do you actually mean making your app target Windows 10, but also be backward compatible with Windows 8.1?

Comment: Or do you simply mean - how do I use relative panels and triggers while still using VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

So much has changed since Windows 8.1...

You have options on how to go proceed that would depend on many factors - like your resources (time, people, money...) or the composition of your user base.

Your best bet might be to build a separate UI for Windows 10 and reuse mostly just the view models. Possibly simply move the 8.1 version on a back burner and only fix problems and continue working on Windows 10 version separately. This would save you from having too many test dimensions in your code to do API checks etc.

The careful and cheap option is to only add specific new features lighting up on new versions of the OS using API checks.

Comment: Thanks filip your reply me :) but can you give a template for this, by using VisualsStateManager i can change the screen sizes ?

Comment: A sample for using `RelativePanel`? You can check here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/07/06/uwp-new-controls-part-1-relativepanel/ (found on https://www.bing.com/search?q=relativepanel%20visualstatemanager%20example )

Comment: Hello Filip,
i am developing a windows store app. 8.1 using visual studio 2013. OS is window 10 Home Edition.
the design i have in portrait view and  resolution is 1080 * 1920.
when it screen change from portrait to landscape it should fits the screen size and controls e.g text boxes, buttons, header etc should response with screen change...
i don't know how to achieve this in VS 2013...?
kindly tel me
i am waiting for your reply...
thanks.. :)

Comment: and your mail id...?

Comment: Why would you develop for Windows 8.1 if the OS is Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is using relative panels and triggers while staying on VS 2013 - well, you don't. The thing is though - relative panels and triggers are only there to make things slightly simpler to do. You can still achieve similar or same results in Windows 8.1 with some custom code.

1. You can use separate templates for your UI and switch them when the size changes.
2. You can handle size changes in code behind and rearrange elements and properties from there.
3. You can build a custom `VisualStateManager` and/or custom panels that do the same things as you get from the responsive design features in Windows 10, although that's possibly writing a lot of throwaway code that you wouldn't need anymore as soon as you could move to newer versions of VS and drop support for older versions of the OS.

Comment: Hi filip,I am working on Windows Store App 8.1 at Windows 10 Pro. Its working fine at all resolutions. But it crashed at startup when I launched it at 1920 * 1080 Landscape mode with 125% zoom. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: @IrfanElahi How about 150%? 200? 225? If it happens for all higher scales, then a likely cause is that something doesn't fit resulting in a layout problem. More likely - there's just a layout cycle happening and those may be difficult to investigate.Check what the exact error/exception is to look for clues. Check for `SizeChanged` events you might be handling by triggering further layout updates. Finally, I often find the most reliable way to locate these is to do a binary search - removing and re-adding subtrees until the issue stops. Sometimes switching `UseLayoutRounding` on element helps.

Comment: hi filip, how are you..?
what is your email..?

Comment: @IrfanElahi filip dot skakun at gmail dot com